# Android WebView - CSS not working

Tags: android, css, webview

Using Android 5.0.2...

The following is not showing up properly. I am unable to see any styling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .bodyBG{
                background: linear-gradient(#88DDFF, #55AAFF);
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background-position: 0, 0;
                background-size: 100%, 100%;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bodyBG">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The WebView is loaded with the HTML like that.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.html_page);
byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(bytes);
final String html = new String(bytes);
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSWebApp(), "app");
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If it is the gradient that's not working, try using vendor-prefix syntax in addition: `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#88DDFF, #55AAFF)`. Apart from that, please describe *what is not working*.

Comment: Also, remove the `,` from `background-size: 100%, 100%;`. The `,` in the syntax is only being used for multiple backgrounds.

Comment: I have run your code in android lollypop..it is working fine..Where you put the html file and how you are fetching it? can you please add some more code?

Comment: The entire CSS is not working for me.  I put the HTML file in the /res/raw folder.